# mediaelement autoplay on load, launch function when finished

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I'm using media play, I'd like to have the audio file automatically play on page load, and then when it finishes launch a function, and I'm having a hard time with that.

To autoplay I thought all I had to do was add preload="auto" into the html like so:

```
<audio id="player2" src="audio/budget.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" preload="auto">
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  So I tried using the success like so:

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
       $("#player2").play(); 
});
```

but this also didn't work.  I'm assuming the success is also where the function would go when you want to fire a function on the audio finishing?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, struggling a little with it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working using this:

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
        mediaElement.play();
        mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function (e) {
                alert("finished");
        }, true);
    }
});
```